# Do I have to stick to a class throughout an entire MvM campaign?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

I have bought 4 MvM tour tickets. Enough to get a botkillers, or I have been told at least. Anyway, so I have a few questions. I plan on playing one of 3 classes:

- Engie
- Pyro
- Soldier

Now, do I have to play as one class throughout all four tickets?

Further to this, if we fail a mission, do we get to start over? Or is that it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play as whatever class you want and switch at will between waves. After switching class you can refund the money spend on other classes to spend it on your new class.

At the end of a level you will go back to the menu and chooses another map to play on meaning character wise you will start a fresh selecting a new class.

MVM needs good team work and by picking a class ahead of time you are already negatively impacting your chances. You need to look at what other players are playing as and choose a class to suite the situation.

The 3 classes you have listed and however some of the most useful. The pyro is good at taking out tanks. The soldier is a decent damage dealer. and the engineers sentry's are handy against large waves of weaker enemies.

If you fail a wave you can keep trying till you complete it. The only issue here is people tend to start leaving the game after a few losses.

Comment: "You may not be able to reallocate points spent on other classes however." Your instructions are... obsolete.  Valve now allows you to refund all the money you spent between every round an unlimited number of times.

Comment: I will update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also note that there is an achievement: **Hack of All Trades** - which requires you to play a full mission (i.e. one map of all waves) as a single class. [See here](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mann_vs._Machievements)

Answer (score 0):

You can always switch classes between waves. You should however think about picking the class you think will have the most effect.